# Mapping request parameter names to fields in @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to add validation on each `@RequestParam` in a controller method, like `@NotNull` for strings, `@Min` for integers. So I decided to have one model class with all request parameters. But now I want to map request parameters names to the fields in `ModelAttribute`. For instance, something like

```
class Model{
   @Param("user-id") //is there any such way
   @Min(1)
   private Integer id;

}
```

I am not able to find any such functionality. Can someone help?

Comment: You cannot find it because it doesn't exist. So no there isn't such a solution, Spring binds parameters directly to properties following the Java Bean Spec.

Comment: is there any way to override the functionality that maps request parameters to ModelAttribute?

Comment: By reimplementing the binding features of the framework.